# How to add parameters to a subscriber callback function given that it is also an action_client

Tags: ros, callback, boost, action-server, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm new to ROS and my situation is the following:
I have a node which subscribes to a Topic, so of course I have my callback function (which by the way uses a custom message so the problem may be there, I don't know. I don't really know C++ either :D ).
The point is that this node must also be a client for an actionlib Client-Server structure.
So every time my node reads something from the topic it is subscribed to, I need also to inform my actionlib Server.
This is why I need to have a "Client" parameter in my callback function, to send also a message to the Server.

My callback SHOULD look like this:

```
void polygonCallback(const es_1::Draw msg, Client* cl){//Stuff}
```

And I just defined "Client" like this

```
typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<es_1::polygonAction> Client;
```

Now, I found online that to do what I want to do I sould use `boost::bind()` and I did. Just like this:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<es_1::Draw>("draw", 1000, boost::bind(polygonCallback,_1,&client));
```

But when I try to "catkin_make" this is the error that pops out:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/publisher.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/canniz/Desktop/catkin_ws/src/es_1/src/polygon_action_client.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::_bi::list2<A1, A2>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = void (*)(es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> >, actionlib::SimpleActionClient<es_1::polygonAction_<std::allocator<void> > >*); A = boost::_bi::list1<const boost::shared_ptr<const es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> > >&>; A1 = boost::arg<1>; A2 = boost::_bi::value<actionlib::SimpleActionClient<es_1::polygonAction_<std::allocator<void> > >*>]’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:47:59:   required from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(const A1&) [with A1 = boost::shared_ptr<const es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> > >; R = void; F = void (*)(es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> >, actionlib::SimpleActionClient<es_1::polygonAction_<std::allocator<void> > >*); L = boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<actionlib::SimpleActionClient<es_1::polygonAction_<std::allocator<void> > >*> >; boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:159:11:   required from ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<FunctionObj, R, T0>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> >, actionlib::SimpleActionClient<es_1::polygonAction_<std::allocator<void> > >*), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<actionlib::SimpleActionClient<es_1::polygonAction_<std::allocator<void> > >*> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:940:38:   required from ‘void boost::function1<R, T1>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> >, actionlib::SimpleActionClient<es_1::polygonAction_<std::allocator<void> > >*), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<actionlib::SimpleActionClient<es_1::polygonAction_<std::allocator<void> > >*> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:728:7:   required from ‘boost::function1<R, T1>::function1(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> >, actionlib::SimpleActionClient<es_1::polygonAction_<std::allocator<void> > >*), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<actionlib::SimpleActionClient<es_1::polygonAction_<std::allocator<void> > >*> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1077:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> >, actionlib::SimpleActionClient<es_1::polygonAction_<std::allocator<void> > >*), boost::_bi::list2<boost::arg<1>, boost::_bi::value<actionlib::SimpleActionClient<es_1::polygonAction_<std::allocator<void> > >*> > >; R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/home/canniz/Desktop/catkin_ws/src/es_1/src/polygon_action_client.cpp:29:102:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313:35: error: could not convert ‘(& a)->boost::_bi::list1<A1>::operator[]<const boost::shared_ptr<const es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> > >&>(boost::_bi::storage1<boost::arg<I> >::a1_<1>)’ from ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> > >’ to ‘es_1::Draw_<std::allocator<void> >’
         unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);
                                   ^
es_1/CMakeFiles/polygon_action_client.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'es_1/CMakeFiles/polygon_action_client.dir/src/polygon_action_client.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [es_1/CMakeFiles/polygon_action_client.dir/src/polygon_action_client.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1462: recipe for target 'es_1/CMakeFiles/polygon_action_client.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [es_1/CMakeFiles/polygon_action_client.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Please if someone knows how to solve this problem would be fantastic... I'm sure the solution is just changing a couple of characters, but I need to know which character.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267948/how-to-add-parameters-to-a-subscriber-callback-function-given-that-it-is-also-an-action_client/) by [Canni](https://answers.ros.org/users/31425/canni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, change your callback argument `const es_1::Draw msg` to `const es_1::Draw::ConstPtr& msg`.

As mentioned in section 2.2. of [roscpp tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber), "The message is passed in a [boost shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm)"

Now since callback accepts the arguments as boost::shared_ptr, you may encapsulate your action client like this:

`boost::shared_ptr<Client> client;`

`client.reset(new Client(..));    // initialize`

`ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<es_1::Draw>("draw", 1000, boost::bind(polygonCallback, _1, client));`

...

`void polygonCallback(const es_1::Draw::ConstPtr &msg, const boost::shared_ptr<Client> &cl){//Stuff} // use cl by ->`

---

Originally posted by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) with karma: 161 on 2017-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Canni](https://answers.ros.org/users/31425/canni/) on 2017-08-03**:
Thank you so much! I didn't study c++ so all this stuff is absolutely new to me. One day maybe I'll understand in detail what I'm doing ahahah
Now it's compiling!